# How do I set tint color only for non white parts of the UIImage?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Simple I have UIImageView icon with two people and it looks like this:

[image]

but when I set `tintColor` to red it looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid covering every non *zero-alpha* pixel? I need to show the **tie** really there. One time I need people red, other time green.

The icon is simple png file. Rounded circle is simple background color of UIImageView. So the part of the image with **tie** cannot be *zero-alpha*.

Is there any way to achieve such effect **WITHOUT** creating images for every color?

Comment: Why don't you use two image ?

Comment: Because the color I need to change dynamically. One time it may be green, other time red or black...

Comment: Core Image. Specifically, using GLSL to write your own CIKernel. It's actually pretty straightforward.

Comment: @dfd pretty straightforward? Please help... I completely do not know core image...:)

Comment: I see, then you have to get the people image separate from the circle image, and set it through autlayout in that circle image, now you can set tint colour for your people image.

Comment: Do you just need the silhouettes to change color? Or also the circle portion?

Comment: without circle... only silhouettes

Answer (score 1):

This was similar to another idea I had been playing around with, so I did a little more fiddling...

Starting with these 3 images:

[image] [image] [image]

and then using them as `.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)` to give the desired colors... and then layering them via `CALayer` to get:

[image]

and an "exploded" view for clarity...

[image]

<s>Create an image where the "people" are 100% transparent - effectively "holes" in the image.</s>

Set the background color of the UIImageView to be the "fill" color.

You can still mask it with a circle (CAShapeLayer, for example), if you don't want a white bounding-box as part of the image.

Original images:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFrmB.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GNDX.png

Comment: it looks quite good;) but... what if I need to change the background of circle? What I actually do? The reason? Need to show where it is selected or not... no other way to do this? For now +1

Comment: You can get "fancy" with multiple layers of image and mask combinations... would take a little playing around with, but not out of the question. Another option... since your image is so simple, it wouldn't take much at all to switch from png to a couple Bezier paths + fill operations. Would scale well too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CISpotColor filter:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISpotColor

This allows you to specify a color in your image that is to be changed into another color. Thus, since you know the original color of the tie and the background, you can change either of them, or both, in a single move.